# How to copy file attributes from one file to another in Java?

Tags: java, file, attributes, copy

How can I copy file attributes (creation time, modification  time, etc...) from one file to another in Java, and just the attributes? (not the file itself)

Similarly to `touch -r file1 file2`, which is what I ended up doing calling it remotely (`Runtime.getRuntime().exec("touch -r file1 file2")`), but in a Java way (and potentially system agnostic).

I've seen a few other threads about copying mp3/mp4 attributes, but in my case I am interested in the file attributes (without actually copying the file, only its attributes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'new' (it's over 10 years old at this point) `Files` API does have facilities both for common attributes (such as 'last modified', which all filesystems/OSes tend to have), as well as specific attributes (such as posix ones, including owner/group), in a pluggable fashion.

You can at the very least use these APIs to copy over the common attributes, as well as the posix-special ones, and given that you mentioned `touch -r`, that's probably all you need.

[`Files` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html). Check in particular `readAttributes`, `setAttribute`, `set/getPosixFilePermissions`.

Comment: Interestingly, my class had another `Files` (`com.google.common.io.Files`) in the path, which is why I didn't see these functions... Thanks!